# Matplotlib: customize default pyplot.errorbar() style

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to specify the default values of `kwargs` when using `errorbar()`, for instance, to set `ecolor = 'r'` by default.

The `matplotlibrc` configuration file only supports `errorbar.capsize`, so that's out. I guess I could define a wrapper function and use it instead of `errorbar()`, but is there no way to change default values in the original function?

Comment: May be [this](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) is of use to you

Comment: `ecolor` defaults to the color of the line, i.e. the current color of the color cycler. You could set the colors of the colorcycler to red if that is desired. Else there is no way to change the default.